# Vectorise summation with missing elements

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I wish to solve the following sum `s`, which is defined element-wise:

[image]

where elements of `z` and `lambda` are of complex type and `N` is real and the length of the vectors. This can be done in a loop, though it is inefficient. Here is my lopped solution:

```
import numpy as np

N = 10
z = np.random.rand(N)
lamb = np.random.rand(N)

s = []
indexs = np.arange(N)

for idx in indexs:

    summand = np.sum(1/(z[idx] - lamb[indexs[indexs!=idx]]))

    s.append(summand/N)

s = np.array(s)
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of a full `numpy` solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

N = 10
z = np.random.rand(N)
lamb = np.random.rand(N)
ss = 1 / np.subtract.outer(z, lamb)
np.fill_diagonal(ss, 0)
ss = ss.sum(axis=1) / N
```

Answer (score 1):

You could subtract `lamb` with broadcasting generating this way a `(len(z),len(lamb))` shaped array, then set its diagonal entries to `0` with [`fill_diagonal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) so that they satisfy `lamb[indexs[indexs!=idx]]` and `sum` along the second axis:

```
out = z[:,None]-lamb
np.fill_diagonal(out, 0)
out = (1/out).sum(1)/N
```